# Using squares to represent counts in a map

Tags: javascript, d3.js, visualization, geo

This might be a simple question, but I have a map in d3 and I'd like to represent event-counts as squares.

Here's an example png of what I'm going for:

[image: rough sketch]

They're not aligned perfectly in the picture, but let's say I have a JSON:

```
[
    {city:'New York', count:3},
    {city:'Washington, D.C.', count:1},
    {city:'Austin', count:5},
    {city:'Havana', count:8}
]
```

of counts that I'd like to represent as squares, preferably clustered in an orderly way.

I'm scratching my head on this — I think maybe a force-directed graph will do the trick? I've also seen this: http://bl.ocks.org/XavierGimenez/8070956 and this: http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4063269 that might get me close.

For context and set-up (I don't need help making the map, but just to share), here's the repo I'm using for the project: https://github.com/alex2awesome/custom-map, which shows the old way I was representing counts (by radius of a circle centered on each city).

Comment: Another possible avenue might be using a `treemap()`? http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4063582

Comment: does someone at least know what this might be called? I'm not even sure what to google right now — trying `d3 layout pack rectangles` isn't getting me very far.

Comment: making each counting-group an equal-sized partition might be promising: http://animateddata.co.uk/slides/d3-layouts/partition.html. Computationally feasible?

Comment: also super promising: http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1009139 Mike Bostock's square grid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> does someone at least know what this might be called?

The technical name of this in dataviz is *pictogram*.

Here is a general code for plotting the rectangles, you'll have to change some parts according to your needs. The most important part is the calculation for the rectangles `x` and `y` position, using the [modulo operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators).

First, let's set the initial position and the size of each rectangle. You'll have to set this according to your coordinates.

```
var positionX = 5;
var positionY = 5;
var size = 5;
```

Then, let's set how many rectangles you want (this, in your code, will be `d.count`):

```
var count = 15;
var gridSize = Math.ceil(Math.sqrt(count));
var data = d3.range(count);
```

Based on the count, we set the `gridSize` (just a square root) and the `data`.

Now we plot the rectangles:

```
var rects = svg.selectAll(".rects")
    .data(data)
    .enter()
    .append("rect");

rects.attr("width", size)
    .attr("height", size)
    .attr("x", function(d,i){ return positionX + (i%gridSize)*(size*1.1)})
    .attr("y", function(d,i){ return positionY + (Math.floor((i/gridSize)%gridSize))*(size*1.1) })
    .attr("fill", "red");
```

Here is a working snippet, using 15 as count (4, 9, 16, 25 etc will give you a perfect square). Change `count` to see how it adapts:

```js
var svg = d3.select("body")
 .append("svg")
 .attr("width", 50)
 .attr("height", 50);
 
var count = 15;
var size = 5;
var positionX = 5;
var positionY = 5;
var gridSize = Math.ceil(Math.sqrt(count));
var data = d3.range(count);

var rects = svg.selectAll(".rects")
 .data(data)
 .enter()
 .append("rect");
 
rects.attr("width", size)
 .attr("height", size)
 .attr("x", function(d,i){ return positionX + (i%gridSize)*(size*1.2)})
 .attr("y", function(d,i){ return positionY + (Math.floor((i/gridSize)%gridSize))*(size*1.2) })
 .attr("fill", "red");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I forgot to mention: that value "1.2" in `x`  and `y` positions is the space between the rectangles (that is, 20℅ of their sizes).

Comment: thanks @gerardo, this is great and relatively simple! sometimes I get so caught up in searching for libraries that I don't think through the mechanics of implementing something from scratch

Comment: @GerardoFurtado whats the reason behind square root in `var gridSize = Math.ceil(Math.sqrt(count));`

Comment: @alt255 Because I need a square for distributing the points. For instance, with 15 points, it gives us a 4x4 grid (4 is `Math.ceil(Math.sqrt(15))`. For instance, if we had 17 points, it would give us 5x5.